# Camera tracking

Tags: camera, tracking

After tracking, I wanted to import one of my own objects to the scene. Now when I play the animation, as the camera moves the object also keeps on moving. It doesn't stay fixated at one place. How do I fix this?[image]

Comment: It's very hard to understand what is going on without  seeing the original video you are dealing with, and the 3d scene from a view that is not the camera view. Please read :https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/2309#2309 to learn how to create short videos that can be posted on this site. Then use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information that might help us how you tracked the scene and how set up your project.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience caused. Here's the link https://gfycat.com/DrearyNextGhostshrimp

Comment: again... show a gif  of the 3d scene from a view that is not the camera view but that includes the camera, the objects and the tracked points. Also, the nodes on the right of the image do not help to understand the scene, so don't include them in the image, or if you want to show them show them completely. Again... add more information that might help us how you tracked the scene, What is the projection error? how did you determine the placement of the cup on the scene? Please read through the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329